# Map one range of values to another in VBScript

Tags: algorithm, function, vbscript, dictionary

I need to translate a value in the range 1-320 to it's equivalent value within the spread in the range 500-2500, and I need to do it in VBScript.

Is there a function similar to map() that can do this for me? I can't include any external libraries in this particular use case.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent value"?? Are you just looking for a linear function like that in @phimuemue's answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean you want to convert any number between 1 and 320 to its corresponding number between 500 and 2500 such that 1 corresponds to 500 and 320 corresponds to 2500?

If so, you can do it as follows: Let `x` be your original number (between 1 and 320) and `y` be the target number (between 500 and 2500):

```
y = ((x-1)/319) * 2000 + 500
```

In general, if you have a range `a1` to `a2` and want to convert it to range `b1` to `b2` using

```
y = ((x - a1)/(a2 - a1)) * (b2 - b1) + b1
```

Comment: thanks, i feel a bit stupid for even asking this now i've seen the answer :)